# Toad for MySQL integration with SVN - Commit fails, comments required

Tags: mysql, svn, toad, pre-commit-hook

We use Subversion for source control and have implemented a pre-commit hook that checks for comments and does not allow commits without comments.

I use Toad for MySQL 5 to manage the DB. It provides a way to integrate with SVN and put DB in source control but it does not provide a way to add comments as part of the commit.

Is there a way
either a) provide a default comment to svn so that the pre-commit hook that checks for comments gets it or b) a way to override the pre-commit hook that checks for comments just for the Toad client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell who is doing the commit (the author) using svnlook, so you could try setting a specific user for the Toad client - but that's not likely to be acceptable.

The alternative is to allow blank commits for specific file types (or repo paths) in the pre-commit hook script itself.

You cannot interfere with the suppled transaction in the pre-commit hook, only inspect it and accept or reject it. There is no client "host-agent" supplied in the transaction.